# Display Image in Php From Byte String

Tags: php, mongodb

Because my English ability was insufficient,

please acknowledge it beforehand

Using MongoDB (GridFS), brought the image.

```
$bucket = $this->mDB->selectGridFSBucket([
               'bucketName' => $collection,
               'readPreference' => new MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference::RP_SECONDARY),
            ]);

$stream = $bucket->openDownloadStream($id);
$im = stream_get_contents ( $stream );
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $im;
```

Example : https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/tutorial/gridfs/

However, it is difficult to output this as an image.

What should I do?

[remove header('Content-Type: image/png')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSaBT.png)

[added header('Content-Type: image/png')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9o0v.png)

Comment: You could try `imagecreatefromstring( $im );`

Comment: @RamRaider result is i.stack.imgur.com/H9o0v.png , url : 13.124.109.93/httpapi/get.cover.thumbnail.image.php?query=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally untested but given the nature of the data shown in the image you could try using `imagecreatefromstring` - something along these lines:

```
$bucket = $this->mDB->selectGridFSBucket([
               'bucketName' => $collection,
               'readPreference' => new MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference( MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference::RP_SECONDARY ),
            ]);

$stream = $bucket->openDownloadStream( $id );
$im = imagecreatefromstring( stream_get_contents ( $stream ) ) ;
if( $im ){
    header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
    imagepng( $im );
    imagedestroy( $im );
}
```

---

You might try `base64_decode` on the stream data ( I really don't know what the content of the stream is )

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring( base64_decode( stream_get_contents ( $stream ) )  );
if( $im ){
    header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
    imagepng( $im );
    imagedestroy( $im );
}
```

Comment: result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9o0v.png  , url : http://13.124.109.93/httpapi/get.cover.thumbnail.image.php?query=2